# Move element to end of array

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following question (from AlgoExpert):

> You're given an array of integers and an integer. Write a function that moves all instances of that integer in the array to the end of the array and returns the array.
> The function should perform this IN-PLACE and doesn't need to maintain the order of the other integers.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> array = [2,1,2,2,2,3,4,2]
> toMove = 2
>
> Expected = [1,3,4,2,2,2,2,2] 
>            (the numbers 1,3,4 could be ordered differently)
> ```

#### My code:

```
def moveElementToEnd(array, toMove):
    l = 0
    r = len(array) - 1
    while l < r:
        if array[l] == toMove and array[r] == toMove:
            r -= 1
        elif array[l] != toMove and array[r] != toMove:
            l += 1
        elif array[l] == toMove and array[r] != toMove:
            array[l], array[r] = array[r], array[l]
            l += 1
            r -= 1
    return array
```

This gets timed out, but when I change the if statements as follows, it works fine:

```
def moveElementToEnd(array, toMove):
    if len(array) < 1:
        return array
    l = 0
    r = len(array) - 1
    while l < r:
        if array[l] == toMove and array[r] != toMove:
            array[l], array[r] = array[r], array[l]
            l += 1
            r -= 1      
        elif array[l] != toMove and array[r] != toMove:
            l += 1
        else:
            r -= 1
    return array
```

What causes the timeout in the first code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code block can give an infinite loop, as there are cases where the loop does not change either of the indexes. This is because your `if ..elif..` construct has no catch-all at the end (using `else`)

So it is this part that has a problem:

```
        if array[l] == toMove and array[r] == toMove:
            r -= 1
        elif array[l] != toMove and array[r] != toMove:
            l += 1
        elif array[l] == toMove and array[r] != toMove:
            array[l], array[r] = array[r], array[l]
            l += 1
            r -= 1
```

It doesn't do anything when `array[l] != toMove` and `array[r] == toMove`, and so the loop will run infinitely.

You can picture the four possibilities as follows:

|  | `array[r] == toMove` | `array[r] != toMove` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `array[l] == toMove` | 1 | 2 |
| `array[l] != toMove` | 3 | 4 |

Your faulty code deals with cases 1, 4 and 2 (in that order), but not with 3

The working code deals with cases 2 and 4 first, and in the final `else` it deals with cases 1 and 3 together.

What you want to happen in those four cases is:

|  | `array[r] == toMove` | `array[r] != toMove` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `array[l] == toMove` | `r-=1` | swap, `l+=1; r-=1` |
| `array[l] != toMove` | `r-=1` | `l+=1` |

The fix for your code is thus to change this:

```
if array[l] == toMove and array[r] == toMove:
```

to this:

```
if array[r] == toMove:
```

So it deals with two cases in one go.

And with that change, the second condition can be simplified: if execution gets there, we know that `array[r] != toMove`, so it does not need to be tested. It is also no longer needed to have a second `elif` condition, as that condition will be true whenever the execution gets there. You can change it to an `else`.

```
    if array[r] == toMove:
        r -= 1
    elif array[l] != toMove:
        l += 1
    else:
        array[l], array[r] = array[r], array[l]
        l += 1
        r -= 1
```

And this version is even more concise than the working version you presented.

Comment: So that is the main reason why it is bad practice not to write else at the end of if-elif statements?

Comment: And I am still not sure why on the second code block I do catch all scenarios

Comment: @nomno It is not "bad practice" to use `else` in general. Rather in *your current code* your logic has a flaw. Those are two different statements.

Comment: In the second block it works fine, because it deals with all possible cases: the final `else` deals with the cases where `array[r] == toMove`.

Comment: I added a bit more analysis to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sort` with a custom `key` that compares each element to `toMove`. All the `False` values will be to the left, and all the `True` values will be to the right. Therefore all the `toMove` values will end up at the back of the list.

```
>>> array = [2,1,2,2,2,3,4,2]
>>> toMove = 2
>>> array.sort(key=lambda i: i == toMove)
>>> array
[1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```